# starting network interface in debug mode

Tags: networking, redhat-enterprise-linux, debug

Is it possible to start the network interface in debug mode?
I am looking for Something like "sshd -ddd" but for a network interface. Basically I am looking for a redhat based solution.

Comment: Define "debug mode".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A network interface cannot be "started in debug mode", however, if you want to inspect the network traffic specifically for one interface, the simplest and most commonly used solution is to use `tcpdump(8)`. One example would be:

```
# tcpdump -vvv -s0 -i $interface
```

Check the manpage for further options.